# Feeling of closeness with something you adore/love so much

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, spoken-english

How do I say that I find a person or place so good or you love it so much that you think it gives you feeling of closeness to it? Or what? 
E.g I like my friend's mother so much, it's like motherly vibes come out of her. 
Or
I like a place so much, it gives me homely/comfy feeling, seems like a second home to me.
What is this feeling called?

Comment: You can just say that this place makes part of your life, or you are very close to a person or to someone, or simply say that someone/thing is very special for you

Comment: No, there got to be some term for It ?

Comment: I guess not, there is no term for this, you can use different words to emphasize that someone/thing is very special for you by saying things like: _I see you as if you were my sister, we are so close_ - _I feel like this place was my home, I always feel better when I get here_

Answer (score 1):

There is no **unique** term, e.g. from psychology, for feelings like that.  There are a few for feelings of unification with the world or entire universe and all creatures in it, but not for deep feelings of closeness and identification with one person or one place.  The best you can do is *describe* the feeling.

Use **relationship** and/or **emotional** terms:

> "She's **like a sister** to me".
>
> "My friend's mum is so nice that **I feel (like / as though)** she's my mother too"
>
> "I love Minneapolis.  **It's as though** I've lived here all my life"

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a single word to describe such a feeling, and that word is *intimacy*, and this can be used in reference to a person, or a location.

> **[intimacy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intimacy):**
>
> 1. a state marked by emotional closeness *(the intimacy of old friends)*
> 2. a quality suggesting closeness or warmth *(the cafe's intimacy)*
> 3. something that is very personal or private *(They shared little intimacies in their letters.)*

However, *intimacy* (the state of being intimate) is most often used these days to describe physical intimacy, which comes from having a sexual relationship, and one must be careful when using the word to describe a platonic relationship that the listener does not interpret your sentence in this fashion. telling your friend, for example, that you have an *intimate* relationship with his mother, without further clarification, may not end well.

Is you wish to err on the side of caution , (and most people do), another term might be a safer bet, such as *affinity*.

> [**affinity**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity): a feeling of closeness and understanding that someone has
>   for another person because of their similar qualities, ideas, or
>   interests

Or, as other comments have suggested, you can simply describe the connection witht is person or place as *closeness*, or *being close*.

Answer (score 0):

I have frequently heard the word "nostalgic" being used for some of feelings you describe. However, the dictionary definitions seem to omit the all the 'sweetness' of the feeling.

*Nostalgia* - (noun)
1. a wistful desire to return in thought or in fact to a former time in one's life, to one's home or homeland, or to one's family and friends; a sentimental yearning for the happiness of a former place or time.

*nostalgic* - (adjective)
1. experiencing or exhibiting nostalgia, a sentimental or wistful yearning for the happiness felt in a former place, time, or situation.